# Linux Shell scripting sed command

Tags: bash, sed

```
sed -r -i -e "s/AppId/$a/" -e "s/AccessToken/$b/" FacebookApi > /script/newapp
```

By giving this command why the program is not getting executed can you solve this please ?

Comment: Remove `-i` or output redirection `> /script/newapp`.

Answer (score 1):

sed is an editor, not a shell interpretor. It execute SED instruction like subistitute for `s///` but not batch or binary of other form (than sed instruction). Execution stay at calling shell level and management (like variable substition between double quote in a sed instruction string that is treated before sed receive the full instruction)

Answer (score 0):

The command is executed. As you specified `-i` it is modifying the specified file in place (and not generating any output).

From the `sed` man page:

> ```
> -i extension
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length
> extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
> ```

As `sed` is directly modifying `FacebookApi` standard output will be empty (as the file `/script/newapp`)

Comment: yeah you are right am not getting the exact output it is empty.so how to modify it ?

Comment: actually i need to store the output in a new file

Comment: Do not use the -i option. If you specify "in place" sed will do the substitution "in place"